# What might the (normalized) pair correlation function of prime numbers look like?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Cross-posting from [Math.Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58168/what-might-the-normalized-pair-correlation-function-of-prime-numbers-look-like).

---

You might have read about the [fortuitous meeting between Montgomery and Dyson](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/the-spectrum-of-riemannium). The background is that the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function, when normalized to have unit spacing on average, (seem to) have the pair correlation function $1-\mathrm{sinc}^2(x)$, where $\mathrm{sinc}$ is the normalized function $\sin(\pi x)/ (\pi x)$. It's still a conjecture but it has good [numerical support](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2007890).

So what about prime numbers? Let $\Sigma(x,u)$ be the number of pairs of primes $p,q\le x$ which satisfy the inequality $0\le p-q\le \frac{x}{\pi(x)}u$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. This inequality is chosen because multiplying primes by $\frac{\pi(x)}{x}$ will ensure the gaps between consecutives is exactly unity (hence they are normalized). Then what might

$$g(u)=\frac{d}{du}\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\Sigma(x,u)}{\pi(x)}\right)$$

end up looking like? This basically asks, "what is the density of normalized primes around so-and-so apart from each other?" (You can see the original Montgomery conjecture as equation 12 [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~hlm/paircor1.pdf). I've adapted it to prime numbers by essentially changing the asymptotic number of zeta zeros to the prime counting function instead. I might be acting presumptuous in assuming the naive replacement will still afford a meaningful answer.)

Comment: Please don't post on MO and M.SE simultaneously. Among other things, it is a bad way of collecting answers in a way useful to other (esp. in the future).

Comment: @David Roberts: Sorry. I've seen other questions posted on both before and wasn't aware it was looked down upon.

Comment: @spec - that's ok. If a question is worth cross-posting, it means it was a bad fit where it was originally posted. And there is a suitable (>2 day, say) delay to allow people to think about it.

Comment: That $\pi(x)$ in the denominator should be $\pi(x)^2$, right? 

Comment: @David Speyer: I'm not sure. I've added in a note at the bottom on how I got the expression, and while I believe I did the adaptation correctly, it may still be a naive substitution and in need of change.

Comment: You may want to take a look at these lectures by Soundararajan: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606408 

Comment:  I think whatever result you get follows from the Cramer random model of the primes, or something similar as modified by Maier. Generically, one has that the density of $x$ with $\pi(x+\lambda\log x)−\pi(x)=k$ should be Poisson distributed as $e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k/k!$. This is a nearest-neighbor statistic, and if I am not wrong, the gap distribution should follow. Sorry I do not know off the top of my head or have a reference yet. 

Comment: Lebeouf does something like this http://www.springerlink.com/content/56542774l0171258/

Comment: Nevermind, I was confused. Your denominator is right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you are asking for the two-point correlation function of a Poisson process with unit density, which is just unity: $g(u)=1$.

the support for this is about as strong as for the Riemann zeroes: there is extensive numerical evidence but no conclusive theorem; see Soundarajan's 2006 paper cited above, or more recent papers on arXiv:0708.2567 and arXiv:1102.3648

the esssential difference between the function $g_R(u)=1-sinc^2(u)$ for the Riemann zeroes and $g(u)=1$ for the prime numbers, is that the former vanishes $\propto u^2$ for small $u$ ("level repulsion"), while the latter remains constant. This is the difference between the (conjectured) Gaussian unitary ensemble of Riemann zeroes and the Poisson ensemble of prime numbers. For large $u$ all correlations decay and $g_R(u)\rightarrow g(u)$.